# Add or Push new item to array

Tags: javascript

How can I add another entry to an array?

Here's my code

```
function addItem(){
  var reimbursementArr = [];

  reimbursementArr.push({
   txnDate: document.getElementById("txnDate").value,
   summaryOfExpense: document.getElementById("summaryOfExpense").value,
   project: document.getElementById("project").value,
   referenceNumber: document.getElementById("referenceNumber").value,
   address1: document.getElementById("address1").value,
   address2: document.getElementById("address2").value,
   city: document.getElementById('city').value,
   country: document.getElementById('country').value,
   serviceCharge: document.getElementById('serviceCharge').value,
   valueAddedTax: document.getElementById('valueAddedTax').value,
   currency: document.getElementById('currency').value,
   amountWithoutVAT: document.getElementById('amountWithoutVAT').value,
   expandedWitholdingTax: document.getElementById('expandedWitholdingTax').value, 
  }); //put to the array
```

Comment: Define the array outside the function if you want to populate the same array with more items. Otherwise you create a new array each time the function is called

Comment: Read more about `var scope`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var // https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp // https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-variable-scope/

Answer (score 2):

Declare the array outside of the function, your array gets intialized to an empty array everytime you call the function `addItem()`. Therefore, your array will not contain the previous entries when it the method is called.

Therefore move the array declaration outside of the function to retain the data.

```
 var reimbursementArr = [];

function addItem(){

  reimbursementArr.push({
   txnDate: document.getElementById("txnDate").value,
   summaryOfExpense: document.getElementById("summaryOfExpense").value,
   project: document.getElementById("project").value,
   referenceNumber: document.getElementById("referenceNumber").value,
   address1: document.getElementById("address1").value,
   address2: document.getElementById("address2").value,
   city: document.getElementById('city').value,
   country: document.getElementById('country').value,
   serviceCharge: document.getElementById('serviceCharge').value,
   valueAddedTax: document.getElementById('valueAddedTax').value,
   currency: document.getElementById('currency').value,
   amountWithoutVAT: document.getElementById('amountWithoutVAT').value,
   expandedWitholdingTax: document.getElementById('expandedWitholdingTax').value, 
  }); //put to the array
```

Comment: Oh! Thats the only thing I missed! Thank you!